# Zendfox theme Url, image url, css url

Tags: php, html, css

Zendfox theme Url for image? I am using this but not working:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getThemeurl(''); ?>" alt="My Logo" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code use in img tag for getting image in Zendfox

---

```
 <img src="<?php echo $this->getThemetUrl('images/image.jpg') ?>" alt="No Image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->themeUrl('images/urimage-name.ext'); ?>" alt="No Image" />
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define your css and js in xml file in zendfox framework:

file path: `zendfox\application\views\web\core\default\layout\fox.xml`
like this:

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```